# Jensen inequality for probability measure

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

The problem is:

> prove that space $L^q(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ is contained in $L^r(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ for any $1 \le r\le q$. where $P$ is probability measure

To prove this is sufficient to prove that $\|Y\|_r\le \|Y\|_q$

Then proof uses a truncated sequence $X_n = (\min(|Y|,n))^r$ to approximate $|Y|^r$,then using Jensen inequality on the truncated sequence. that is:

$(\mathbb{E}[X_n])^{\frac{q}{r}} \le \mathbb{E}[|Y|^q] $.

Then get's the result by monotonic convergence theorem

my question is why we use truncated sequence intead of using $|Y|^r$ replace of $X_n$ above?Is it because of Jensen inequality needs  function integrable?

Is there some example show that random variable or convex function in Jensen inequality is not $L^1$ then it may not hold?

Comment: Doesn't this follow directly from Holder's inequality?

Comment: And yes, to apply Jensen you need integrability but Hölder does not need this.

Comment: How do you define $L^r$ for $r<0$. You don't have norms then

Comment: thanks, I have found Hölder version proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, assume your space is $([0,1],\mathcal{B},\lambda)$ with the latter denoting the Borel-algebra and the Lesbegue measure, and let $Y(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ and consider the convex function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$. Then, $f(Y(x))=x,$ which is clearly in $L^1$. However, $Y$ isn't.

Conversely, taking $f$ to be the same $Y(x)=x$ shows that the other way around might fail as well.

Thus, it is an important assumption that both $Y$ *and* $f(Y)$ are $L^1$-variables, since otherwise, either of the sides of the inequality might not even be defined.

Comment: We need both $Y$ and $fY$ integrable,for the first case,$Y$ is not integrable,the inequality fails is resonable,but for the other direction,we get a finite value $\le$ infinity,since there are only positive part.this definition of integral is allowed. if $fY$ is not always positive,then the integral has no definition.